# Prevent an object from being paged out (VirtualLock equivalent)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, memory-management

How would one go about keep an object in memory such that it won't be paged out by the OS in .Net?

i.e. Something similar to VirtualLock, but operating on an object, such that if compacting occurs and the object is moved it still would not be paged out, etc.. (I suppose one could pin the object's, determine what pages it belongs to, and then VirtualLock those pages, but that seems non-desirable for many reasons.)

If possible, could you point me to a reference or working sample? (C# ideally)

Comment: If you really need that amount of control, why are you writing managed code?

Comment: Well, without getting into managed/non-managed debates, for all the usual reasons to use managed code. :) We would just like a couple infrequently used objects to not be paged out so they're as responsive as possible when they come back. That doesn't seem to be a characteristic exclusive to the non-managed world to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at this one http://www.codeplex.com/NonPagedCLRHost ?

Comment: That's interesting, but we wouldn't want to use a custom host. Anything similar for standard .Net?

Comment: Link does not exist anymore

Answer (score 3):

If you want deterministic response times you should use a real time OS that operates with the limits you specify, not Windows.

By definition, if they are infrequently used, the are high on the list of candidates to be paged out.

Here is a horrible solution: Create a thread (or an asynchronous timer) that once ever INTERVAL ms touches your object then goes back to sleep. Tune INTERVAL until you get the desired behaviour.

Comment: +1 for solution:  this is good as it gets if you must stick with managed code *and* you don't want to use a custom CLR host.