# Can you stop memory from being swapped to disk?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

I was wondering if it was possible to prevent memory of a object (class or struct) from being swapped to disk?

Edit: As for why I've been told some of the data I'm going to be working with cannot be written to disk.
I dont expect it to be left long enough for the data to be swapped out but thought it's worth checking.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this? =)

Comment: You mean besides using it?  Typically worrying about that sort of thing is left up to the operating system.  Simply by using it you reduce the chance of it being placed in your swap space.  If you haven't used it recently, chances are it's ok to place it on disk.  Are you seeing objects that are frequently in use being placed on the disk?

Comment: I smell a micro optimization. How do you know this is a problem for you?

Comment: @Jens One reason you might want this is for security reasons: if you don't want passwords or secret keys persisted to disk, for example.  (Easier to recover than from RAM.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for the [`SecureString` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx), which  will not be swapped to disk.

Comment: I doubt it's what the asker is looking for, but thanks for the link :)

Comment: Is there any reference available which proofs that SecureString does not get swapped? I see that it can be GCed, does not get pooled and is implicitly encrypted. If SecureString does not get swapped, its implementation may give a hint.

Comment: This is not accurate.  SecureString exists especially to avoid seeing the string back in the paging file.

Comment: Hmm. Could be a work round as the original data cannot be store on disk but Im not sure about encripted data...

Comment: SecureString gets swapped to disk just like any other managed memory - but when it does, it's encrypted. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx - To keep things out of the page file use unsafe{} and VirtualLock()

Answer (score 10):

I am still not clear on why you want to do this. In the context of C#, you have to do two things: "pin" the memory so it cannot be relocated by garbage collection, and then lock it so that it doesn't get swapped out.

Here is a nice blog post that describes how to do the first part (pinning):

http://www.matthew-long.com/2005/10/18/memory-pinning/

Now you need the address and extent of the object to be able to invoke `VirtualLock`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa366895

Note that `VirtualLock` only locks pages (units of 4K), so your memory area needs to be at least that large, and aligned to the start of a page. I am assuming that it needs to be invoked in an `unsafe` context, though I am not sure.

Previous posting on the topic:
[Prevent an object from being paged out (VirtualLock equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478405/net-prevent-an-object-from-being-paged-out-virtuallock-equivalent)

Another related blog post:
http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/13/speedy-c-part-3-understanding-memory-references-pinned-objects-and.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is only technically possible.  Memory pages can be locked in RAM with the VirtualLock() API function.  Problem is, that requires supplying the address of the page(s) you want locked.  You can't get this address in any documented way from the garbage collector.  Nor does it make any promise that the *same* address for, say, the gen #0 heap will be repeatable.  For one, the size of that heap is dynamic, usually ranging somewhere between 2 and 8 megabytes, depending on the program's allocation pattern.

Just randomly locking a large range with the hope that you'll catch most of them doesn't work either.  A process gets a quota of lockable pages.  It isn't very large, above all because it is so destabilizing to the operation of the machine.  Dragons live here.

Comment: You would have thought ms would have provided a .net equiv of VirtualLock.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do something totally different:

Build a nice native **wrapping C++ DLL** with your desired functions/allocations/whatever **which will also make sure the data isn't get swapped** (VirtualLock as someone said here). Use it from C#.

After all, natively it's possible, it's just that you're now bound to C#. So, get around it!

Answer (score 0):

Not really, that's an operating system thing.

Just rest assured that Windows' paging strategy will prioritize keeping in memory the most frequently accessed pages, so if a certain page is important for your application, it'll be there as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Um, good question.. you can disable swap in windows completely (size=0), but idk if thats enough to prevent .NET from swapping.

Comment: it looks like this may be the only way :(

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment you can also do this at the OS level instead - just use a really beefy machine with a lot of RAM, and disable paging/swap entirely. It does mean you better not ever overrun that RAM, but that's where the task comes back to C# - you can constrain max memory usage with smart design.

https://www.howtogeek.com/126430/htg-explains-what-is-the-windows-page-file-and-should-you-disable-it/