# C# - Decrypt large files in memory using BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I have a requirement where I need to decrypt large files in memory because these files contain sensitive data (SSNs, DOBs, etc). In other words the decrypted data cannot be at rest (on disk). I was able to use the BouncyCastle API for C# and managed to make it to work for files up to 780 MB. Basically here's the code that works:

```
string PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH = @"c:\pgp\privatekey.gpg";
string PASSPHRASE = "apassphrase";
string pgpData;
string[] pgpLines;
string pgpFilePath = @"C:\test\test.gpg";

Stream inputStream = File.Open(pgpFilePath, FileMode.Open);
Stream privateKeyStream = File.Open(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH, FileMode.Open);
string pgpData = CryptoHelper.DecryptPgpData(inputStream, privateKeyStream, PASSPHRASE);
string[] pgpLines = pgpData.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Console.WriteLine(pgpLines.Length);
Console.ReadLine();

foreach (var x in pgpLines)
{
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In the above code the entire decrypted data is stored in the pgpData string and that's fine for files up to 780MB as stated previously.

However, I will be getting much larger files and my solution above does not work as I get OutOfMemoryExeception exception.

I've been trying the code below, and I keep getting errors when the DecryptPgpData method below is invoked. When using 512 as the chunksize I get a "Premature end of stream in PartialInputStream" exception. When using 1024 as the chunksize I get a "Exception starting decryption" exception. My question is, is this the correct way to decerypt chunks of data using BouncyCastle? The pgp file I'm trying to decrypt was encrypted using the gpg.exe utility. Any help is much appreciated.....It's been almost two days that I've been trying to make this to work with no success.

```
string PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH = @"c:\pgp\privatekey.gpg";
string PASSPHRASE = "apassphrase";
string pgpData;
string[] pgpLines;
string pgpFilePath = @"C:\test\test.gpg";

string decryptedData = string.Empty;
FileInfo inFile = new FileInfo(pgpFilePath);
FileStream fs = null;

fs = inFile.OpenRead();
int chunkSize = 1024;

byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
int totalRead = 0;

while (totalRead < fs.Length)
{
         int readBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
         totalRead += readBytes;


        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        decryptedData = CryptoHelper.DecryptPgpData(stream, privateKeyStream, PASSPHRASE);
                Console.WriteLine(decryptedData);                                     
}

fs.Close();            
Console.WriteLine(totalRead);            
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can't you use EFS to create a local secure storage and read from/write to it as needed? It is designed in such a way that only the user that created it can read it.

Comment: Consider whether you can just avoid this problem. Do you need to have all the decrypted data in memory *at the same time*? Or can you decrypt a bit, do whatever processing is needed, throw it away and then decrypt some more?

Comment: If you have the data in memory, there is a chance that the memory will be paged out to disk. However: [Can you stop memory from being swapped to disk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682225/can-you-stop-memory-from-being-swapped-to-disk).

Comment: Thanks All. Using EFS is not an option where I could have the data decrypted to disk.

Comment: Brian - No, I don't have to have all the data decrypted to memory. I can decrypt a bit do some processing and get some more...and that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually, let's say my pgp file contains 60,000 records (when decrypted). The file in question contains a header row and data rows...each line contains a line feed/carriage return at the end....ideally I would like to decrypt complete lines. For example, if I pass a chunk of data to the BouncyCastle decryption methods it should return the header row plus 10 lines (just an example).....so that I can process completed records....then get the next 10 records, etc..

Comment: Since the last step in CryptoHelper.DecryptPgpData source is convert the stream to a string, why don't you just modify it to return the stream?

Comment: But If I convert it to return a stream....don't you think I would still get memory issues if the entire file is passed as a stream...

Comment: For files larger than 780MB.

Comment: Made it to work :) Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: @user3784295 how were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The below code is for reading blob from Azure Storage Container and Decrypt and pushing into Azure container in chunks. I have tested with 1Gb. works perfectly with out any erros.
Install the PGPCore Nuget package.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.IO;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tt

{

    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {

            string con = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=11111111;AccountKey=aaaaaaaaa=;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string privatekey = ""; // your privatekey

            Stream privatekeyBs64 = ToStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(privatekey)));
            string parspharse = "xxxxx"; // your parspharse

            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(con);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test"); //source container name
            var enc = container.GetBlockBlobReference("10mbonlinenc.txt"); //source blobname
            var encstream = await enc.OpenReadAsync();           

            DecryptFile(
                encstream,
                privatekeyBs64,
                parspharse.ToCharArray(),
                "output.txt", blobClient
            );

            return new OkObjectResult("Success");
        }
        private static async void DecryptFile(
            Stream inputStream,
            Stream keyIn,
            char[] passwd,
            string defaultFileName, CloudBlobClient cb)
        {
            var destcontainer = cb.GetContainerReference("blobpoc"); //your destination container name
            var destblob = destcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference("10mbonlinenc.txt"); //blob name


            int chunksize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; //1mB--> change as per your requirement
            inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);

            try
            {
                PgpObjectFactory pgpF = new PgpObjectFactory(inputStream);
                PgpEncryptedDataList enc;

                PgpObject o = pgpF.NextPgpObject();
                //
                // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
                //
                if (o is PgpEncryptedDataList)
                {
                    enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)o;
                }
                else
                {
                    enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpF.NextPgpObject();
                }

                //
                // find the secret key
                //
                PgpPrivateKey sKey = null;
                PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
                PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(
                    PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn));
                List<string> blocklistids = new List<string>();


                foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pked in enc.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
                {
                    sKey = FindSecretKey(pgpSec, pked.KeyId, passwd);

                    if (sKey != null)
                    {
                        pbe = pked;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (sKey == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("secret key for message not found.");
                }

                Stream clear = pbe.GetDataStream(sKey);

                PgpObjectFactory plainFact = new PgpObjectFactory(clear);

                PgpObject message = plainFact.NextPgpObject();

                if (message is PgpCompressedData)
                {
                    PgpCompressedData cData = (PgpCompressedData)message;
                    PgpObjectFactory pgpFact = new PgpObjectFactory(cData.GetDataStream());

                    message = pgpFact.NextPgpObject();
                }
                byte[] buffer = new byte[chunksize];
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (message is PgpLiteralData)
                {
                    PgpLiteralData ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;

                    Stream sun = ld.GetInputStream();
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    int offset = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = sun.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        Stream actualstream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead);//create stream with actual bytesread
                        
                        ///Create blockId and put that stream into container
                        string blockid = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(offset.ToString("d19")));
                        blocklistids.Add(blockid);
                        await destblob.PutBlockAsync(blockid, actualstream, null); 
                        actualstream.Close(); //close stream
                    }
                    await destblob.PutBlockListAsync(blocklistids); //merge all blobs by passing blocklistids


                }
                else if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
                {
                    throw new PgpException("encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new PgpException("message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
                }

                if (pbe.IsIntegrityProtected())
                {
                    if (!pbe.Verify())
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("message failed integrity check");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("message integrity check passed");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("no message integrity check");
                }
            }
            catch (PgpException e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e);

                Exception underlyingException = e.InnerException;
                if (underlyingException != null)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.Message);
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
        public static Stream ToStream(string str)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(str);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
        public static string toString(Stream stream)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }


        private static PgpPrivateKey FindSecretKey(PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec, long keyID, char[] pass)
        {
            PgpSecretKey pgpSecKey = pgpSec.GetSecretKey(keyID);

            if (pgpSecKey == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return pgpSecKey.ExtractPrivateKey(pass);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code correctly :)
You can do this by wrapping triple backticks (`) around the code